# Unable to install tfjs-node behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tfjs-node, tensorflow.js

I made a tfjs solution for object detection and want to deploy it on server behind corporate proxy.

Problem happens because `tensorflow\tfjs-node\scripts\install.js` does not supprot proxy so it tries to fetch the `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.15.0.zip` directly from server and that isn't possible.'

I've set up my npm config

```
$npm config list
```

and console.log is:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.4 node/v12.18.0 win32 x64"
; userconfig C:\Users\user\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://182.192.254.44:8080/"
proxy = "http://182.192.254.44:8080/"
python = "="
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false
; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\IPA\beauty\TrackingServerProject
; HOME = C:\Users\usename
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

As you can see i get next error because of proxy.

```
$ npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@2.0.1 install C:\IPA\beauty\TrackingServerProject\node_modules\@te
> node scripts/install.js
CPU-windows-2.0.1.zip
* Downloading libtensorflow
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 64.233.189.128:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@2.0.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
```

I think that i maybe need to change `tensorflow\tfjs-node\scripts\install.js` to add proxy ?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work after 3 days problem was in definition of PROXY

tensorflow\tfjs-node\scripts\resources.js  (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/scripts/resources.js)

line 40 & 41

```
const proxy = process.env['HTTPS_PROXY'] || process.env['https_proxy'] ||
      process.env['HTTP_PROXY'] || process.env['http_proxy'] || '';
```

When define proxy in ways 1) or 2) it doesn't detect `process.env`

1. `npm config edit`
2. `.npmrc`

So you need to pass system variable for PowerShell in form of
`$env:HTTP_PROXY="http://182.192.254.44:8080/"`

or for CMD
`HTTP_PROXY=http://182.192.254.44:8080/`

so it will work

just type: `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node` and enjoy!